# how do i display the latest chatter feed of current user using rest api in mobile

Tags: chatter, mobilesdk

Its my first attempt at developing a mobile app. I am using the salesforcemobile sdk and the sample app Contact Explorer within the sdk.

I am trying to get the latest feeds of the current user.

I am able to build the url and pass it out, the question i do have is how would i parse the response object.

```
function onSuccessSfdcChatter(response) {
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
cordova.require("salesforce/util/logger").logToConsole("onSuccessSfdcChatter: received " + response.totalSize + " chatter");

$j("#div_sfdc_chatter_list").html("")
var ul = $j('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a"></ul>');
$j("#div_sfdc_chatter_list").append(ul);

ul.append($j('<li data-role="list-divider">Salesforce Chatter: ' + response.totalSize + '</li>'));
$j.each(response.records, function(i, contact) {
       var newLi = $j("<li><a href='#'>" + (i+1) + " - " + contact.name + "</a></li>");
       ul.append(newLi);
       });

$j("#div_sfdc_chatter_list").trigger( "create" )
}
```

While looping through the response object, `$j.each(response.records, function(i, contact) {`
I am not sure what is that i need to have instead of contact. When the response object returns a contact object i can loop through like i have it now. But when the response returns a feed Item page, how do i loop through to get the latest feed items

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They key here is that the Chatter Feed-Items is returned as an Array (assuming you are accessing any /vxx.0/chatter/feeds/record/xx/feed-items endpoint. The JSON to array handling is done by the Mobile SDK for you. You should then parse it as a regular array (records based on the @items key) received in the response.

Here's an [example](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/03/chatter-api-and-mobile-sdk.html) of how to do it in a native app built using the force.com iOS SDK